# Algorithm on exponential with irrational base

Tags: algorithm, math, exponentiation, exponent

I know there is an `O(logn)` algorithm on calculating `a^n` where `a` is an integer, and `n` is a huge integer (probably the result need to modular another prime `MOD`).

I wondering whether there is still an `O(logn)` algorithm to calculate

> `(a+sqrt(b))^n + (a-sqrt(b))^n (mod MOD)`

The irrational part `sqrt(b)` looks not easy to handle in the exponential calculation. All I can do is to calculate `a+sqrt(b)` and `a-sqrt(b)` part separately and add them together then do the modular, but if `n` is huge, it is easy to overflow. Any ideas?

Comment: The fast exponentiation algorithm only assumes the exponent is an integer. The base can be anything at all. Does that help?

Comment: @templatetypedef Thank you template. Since n is very large, I need to do the modular operation every step, which appears not that straightforward to me if the base contains irrational numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by computing (in Z<sub>M</sub>[x] / ⟨x²-b⟩)

```
(a+x)^n+(a-x)^n mod (M, x^2-b)
```

where again you can use modular halving-and-squaring for the powers, where the intermediate results now are linear polynomials (over modular integers). Actually, you will only need one of the powers, the result is twice the constant coefficient.

---

Alternatively, these power combinations are the solution of the linear recursion of order 2

```
u[n+2]-2*a*u[n+1]+(a^2-b)*u[n]
```

where

```
u[0]=2 and u[1]=2*a
```

so that you can use fast matrix exponentiation of the system matrix of this recursion, again obtaining an O(log(n)) algorithm (disregarding bitsize).

---

**Example:** As per the comment, take a=3, b=8, n=2 (and integers mod M=10^9+7, example is not large enough for that to matter)

In the first variant, compute u[n]=(a+x)^n mod (M, x^2-b), so

```
u[0]=1
u[1]=3+x
u[2]=(3+x)^2 mod (x^2-8)=9+6x+8=17+6x
```

and twice the constant term is 2*17=34

In the second variant, the recursion is (with 2*a=6, a^2-b=1)

```
u[n+2]-6*u[n+1]+u[n]=0
```

so that the first sequence elements are

```
u[0]=2
u[1]=6
u[2]=6*u[1]-u[0]=34
```

Comment: Hi Lutzl, Thank you for your input. I tried some simple cases, but the results are not consistent with what I calculated them directly: a = 3, b = 8, n = 2, x = 10^9+7, the ans should be 2*(3^2+8)=34...

Comment: Works out perfectly nice in both variants, added computation as example.

Comment: Perfect! I mistakenly set x to 10^9+7, now I know it's just a variable all along the iteration. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your alternative approach (u(n) = p*u(n-1)+q*u(n-2)) looks more straightforward to me, and yes the fast matrix multiplication can be used here. While the first one looks not easy to programming due to the modular operation with a variable x part.

Comment: The first is just as easy, it is similar to complex number multiplication. `(c0+c1*x)*(d0+d1*x)=(c0*d0+b*c1*d1)+(c0*d1+c1*d0)*x`.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand `(a+sqrt(b))^n + (a-sqrt(b))^n` you get

```
  ( a + nC1 a^(n-1) √b + nC2 a^(n-2) b + nC3 a^(n-3) √b b + ... )
 +( a - nC1 a^(n-1) √b + nC2 a^(n-2) b - nC3 a^(n-3) √b b + ... )
= 2 a  +  0            + 2 nC2 a^(n-2) b  + 0 + ... + 2 nC4 a^(n-4) b^2 + ...
```

so the terms involving the possibly irrational parts cancel. (nC2 etc are binomial coefficients).

The RHS of the above could be calculated fairly efficiently using integer arithmetic as you can relate each term in the sequence to the previous one. However there are n/2 terms so the calculation is O(n).

As we know the result will be an integer we can try running through the [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm keeping track of the integer a fractional components. Write `a+sqrt(b) = x + y` where x is an integer an y is the fractional part.

Finding the square of this we have `x^2 + 2 x y + y^2`. Even though we are only interested in the integer part we have some problems as there is an integer part of `2 x y+ y^2`. This causes problems as to effectively calculate the integer part we are going to know a lot of digits of `y`. When we come to higher powers you need more an more digits of `y` to get the integer part.

I don't think normal floating point multiplication would be good enough to calculate the terms for very large `n`.